# Postfix Status Contradictory output

Tags: postfix, sles

I have a Suse Enterprise Linux Server with postfix installed. If I run the command `postfix status`, I receive the following contradictory output:

```
postfix: Postfix is running with backwards-compatible default settings
postfix: See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html for details
postfix: To disable backwards compatibility use "postconf compatibility_level=2" and "postfix reload"
postfix/postfix-script: the Postfix mail system is not running
```

I do not understand if my postfix service is running or not.

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems that it's not running:

```
postfix/postfix-script: the Postfix mail system is not running
```